# Hiberante Listener: difference between EventType.POST_INSERT and EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT

Tags: spring, hibernate, listener

### Request

I need to excute a piece of code after every insert in some tables.

I don't want to edit every part of the application looking for all places where the insertion is executed, I would like to use the Hibernate Listener.

### Question

I don't understand the difference between the `EventType`s `POST_INSERT` and `POST_COMMIT_INSERT`. Both refer to the listener `PostInsertEventListener`, but I would like to know which of these I should use, and what are the differences. Both seems will be excecuted after the record is written in the database, maybe one of these is executed only on some special case?

### Other details

I can't (and I don't want to) use a SQL trigger on the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using a `org.hibernate.Interceptor` or a JPA `@PostPersist` listener. The event listener infrastructure is designed for much more sophisticated usecases than yours.